# Wrap a reactive UI in an action button RShiny

Tags: r, tabs, reactive-programming, shiny

I have a tabbed UI that shows up whenever the user selects rows in a datatable (in the following code, the outputs are random, in real life the calculation is quite involved).

I would like to condition the tabbed UI showing up to the click of a button. Currently every time you select an additional row, it does the calculation all over again for the already selected rows. I would like to limit that to a one-time calculation when the user is done selecting all the rows he wants to see.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
```

The UI : the table, the action button and the tabbed section.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    fluidRow(
      column(12,DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = 'tableCurrencies'))
    ),
    actionButton(inputId = 'showSelectedButton',label = 'Show Selec'),
    fluidRow(
      uiOutput("myTabUI")
    )
  )
)
```

The `server` function : If I remove the `output$myTabUI <- eventReactive(input$launchCalcButton, {` part and instead do `output$myTabUI <- renderUI ({ ...` directly it works as intended (minus the calculation following click on the button of course).

```
server <- function(input,output){

  output$tableCurrencies <- DT::renderDataTable({datatable(data.frame(a=rnorm(10),b=rnorm(10),c=rnorm(10)))})

  origTable_selected <- reactive({
    ids <- input$tableCurrencies_rows_selected
    return(ids)
  })

  output$myTabUI <- eventReactive(input$launchCalcButton, {
      selectedTabs <- renderUI({
        myTabs <- lapply(origTable_selected(),function(i) {


          tabName <- paste0("test",i)

          a <- renderPlot({
            hist(rnorm(50))
          })
          output[[paste0(tabName,"rates")]] <- a
          return(tabPanel(
            tabName,
            fluidRow(
              column(6,plotOutput(paste0(tabName,"rates")))
            )
          ))
        })
        return(do.call(tabsetPanel,myTabs))
      })
      selectedTabs
    })
}
app = shinyApp(ui,server)
runApp(app,port=3250,host='0.0.0.0')
```

Not sure how to go about fixing this. Any help welcome.

Comment: Please non't post apps with non-native port/host configurations. This distracts from the actual question and might mess with firewall settings (as it did for me)

Comment: Noted. Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isolate()` to limit reactive dependencies

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    fluidRow(
      column(12,DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = 'tableCurrencies'))
    ),
    actionButton(inputId = 'showSelectedButton',label = 'Show Selec'),
    fluidRow(uiOutput("myTabUI"))
  )
)

server <- function(input,output){
  output$tableCurrencies <- DT::renderDataTable({
    data.frame(a=rnorm(10),b=rnorm(10),c=rnorm(10))})     
  origTable_selected <- reactive({
    input$tableCurrencies_rows_selected        
  })      
  output$myTabUI <- renderUI({
    input$showSelectedButton
    myTabs <- lapply(isolate(origTable_selected()),function(i) {          
      tabName <- paste0("test",i)          
      a <- renderPlot({hist(rnorm(50))})
      output[[paste0(tabName,"rates")]] <- a
      return(tabPanel(
        tabName,
        fluidRow(column(6,plotOutput(paste0(tabName,"rates"))))
      ))
    })
    do.call(tabsetPanel,myTabs)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```